# mvvm dagger 2 ViewModelInjector

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2

there, i need help, im a .NET developer, but now i want to try android.
i downloaded a project from here : https://github.com/gahfy/MVVMPosts

im having problems with the BaseViewModel.kt.
i know that DaggerViewMOdelInjector is created by dagger 2 with my interface ViewModelInjector, but it is not created and i cannot build the project, please help me !!

```
package net.gahfy.mvvmposts.base

import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel
import net.gahfy.mvvmposts.injection.component.DaggerViewModelInjector
import net.gahfy.mvvmposts.injection.component.ViewModelInjector
import net.gahfy.mvvmposts.injection.module.NetworkModule
import net.gahfy.mvvmposts.ui.post.PostListViewModel
import net.gahfy.mvvmposts.ui.post.PostViewModel

abstract class BaseViewModel:ViewModel(){
    private val injector: ViewModelInjector = DaggerViewModelInjector
            .builder()
            .networkModule(NetworkModule)
            .build()

    init {
        inject()
    }

    /**
     * Injects the required dependencies
     */
    private fun inject() {
        when (this) {
            is PostListViewModel -> injector.inject(this)
            is PostViewModel -> injector.inject(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think its better to inject viewModels with constructor injection. Take a look at this article: https://proandroiddev.com/viewmodel-with-dagger2-architecture-components-2e06f06c9455

Comment: Thanks por the comment, im a noobie with android, in this moment, i would like to test this Project to know a little more of this technologys.

Answer (score 0):

update like:- 
`implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger2_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger2_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger2_version"
//    compileOnly "org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1"`